# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException' at

Tags: ios, uitableview, crash

I searched within previous accepted answers for the similar error messages but all they suggest is to update the datasource properly before inserting any row to UITableView (which I think I'm already doing). I'm using a UIRefreshControl (refreshControl) to refresh my UITableView (myTable). And numberOfRowsInSection returns the length of my array of data for table (mainArray) as supposed. Although I seem to update my array data before begin to insert row to my table, application crushes at  [self.myTable endUpdates]; line giving me the following error message:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (15) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (10), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (1 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'

Here is my code:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return mainArray.count;
}

- (void)refresh:(UIRefreshControl *)refreshControl {

    dispatch_queue_t checkQueue = dispatch_queue_create("pull to refresh queue",NULL);

    dispatch_queue_t main = dispatch_get_main_queue();

    dispatch_async(checkQueue, ^{


    NSError *error;

    jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://someurlwithjsondata.json"]];

    if(jsonData != nil)
    {

        newData = [NSJSONSerialization
                   JSONObjectWithData:jsonData
                   options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers|NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves
                   error:&error];

        if (error)
        {

            [refreshControl endRefreshing];

        }
        else
        {

            NSArray *indexPathArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:mainArray.count-1 inSection:0], nil];


            NSMutableArray *values = newData[@"values"];

            for (NSMutableDictionary *value in values)
            {

                [mainArray addObject:value];

            }


            dispatch_async(main, ^{


                [self.myTable beginUpdates];

                [self.myTable insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPathArray withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];

                [self.myTable endUpdates];

                [refreshControl endRefreshing];

            });


        }

    }
    else
    {

        [refreshControl endRefreshing];

    }

});


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is simple. When you reload the table, you are adding 5 objects to your `mainArray` but you only insert one row into the table view via `insertRowsAtIndexPaths:`. These need to match. Insert as many rows as you add to `mainArray`.

Comment: How can i add many row ? `[weakSelf.feedHomeTable insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:_FeedTitleR.count-15 inSection:0]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];` I got this code

Answer (score 0):

Your code is very error prone because you are manually adding rows. Also you are writing the asynchronous code yourself. A much better approach would be to use the success block of AFNetworking to populate 'mainArray' and reload the table rather than all the code you have written. It would look something like this:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

[manager GET:@"http://example.com/resources.json" 
  parameters:nil 
     success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

            ///set mainArray
            [self.myTable beginUpdates];
            [self.myTable endUpdates];

   } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

            NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);

   }];
```